# Asp.net UserControl Implement OnClientClick Event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, custom-controls

I want to create a custom clientside (OnClientClick) event that I can subscribe to in the markup of a asp.net page just like a normal asp.net control included with the framework. Does anyone know of any good examples or tutorials to show how to do this with a user control ?

Say my user control is called AwsomeUserControl.ascx

```
 <asp:AwsomeUserControl OnclientClick='javascript:
   alert('Hello I am a client side alert from a custom control')'/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is basically rendering the given string value to client side.

```
public partial class AwsomeUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string OnClientClick { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OnClientClick))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", 
            OnClientClick, true);
        }
    }
}
```

However, actual ASP.Net Button control's OnClientClick event is a lot more than that. You can view them using Reshaper or some decompile tools.

Here is the source code -

```
/// Adds the attributes of the <see cref="T:System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button"/> control to the output stream for rendering on the client.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="writer">An <see cref="T:System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter"/> that contains the output stream to render on the client. </param>
protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    bool useSubmitBehavior = this.UseSubmitBehavior;
    if (this.Page != null)
        this.Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm((Control)this);
    if (useSubmitBehavior)
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "submit");
    else
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "button");
    PostBackOptions postBackOptions = this.GetPostBackOptions();
    string uniqueId = this.UniqueID;
    if (uniqueId != null && (postBackOptions == null || postBackOptions.TargetControl == this))
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, uniqueId);
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, this.Text);
    bool isEnabled = this.IsEnabled;
    string firstScript = string.Empty;
    if (isEnabled)
    {
        firstScript = Util.EnsureEndWithSemiColon(this.OnClientClick);
        if (this.HasAttributes)
        {
            string str = this.Attributes["onclick"];
            if (str != null)
            {
                firstScript = firstScript + Util.EnsureEndWithSemiColon(str);
                this.Attributes.Remove("onclick");
            }
        }
        if (this.Page != null)
        {
            string backEventReference = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(postBackOptions, false);
            if (backEventReference != null)
                firstScript = Util.MergeScript(firstScript, backEventReference);
        }
    }
    if (this.Page != null)
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(postBackOptions);
    if (firstScript.Length > 0)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, firstScript);
        if (this.EnableLegacyRendering)
            writer.AddAttribute("language", "javascript", false);
    }
    if (this.Enabled && !isEnabled && this.SupportsDisabledAttribute)
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Disabled, "disabled");
    base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
}
```

Comment: I have viewed it using reflector ... this.ViewState["OnClientClick"] = value; I have found that in a setter but I am still looking for what else I need

Comment: Button control overrides AddAttributesToRender event.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a UserControl ?

Comment: UserControl doesn't have AddAttributesToRender, because it can have multiple controls. In other words, it doesn't make sense to add client side onclick event to SqlDataSource. It all depends on what controls you place inside the UserControl. If you start manipulating all those events, you might want to look at Custom Server Control.

Answer (score 1):

You could write like this :

```
protected void print_click(object sender,eventargs e)
{
  //when i click this button i need to call javascript function
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(@"<script language="'javascript'">");
            sb.Append(@"example();");
            sb.Append(@"</script>");
     System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "JCall1", sb.ToString(), false);
}
```

JavaScript can be executed using : [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)
This link could be useful :  [Example: How to execute javascript in C#](http://forums.asp.net/t/1070810.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Give your User-Control a client id and play with it, for example:**

```
<asp:AwsomeUserControl ClientID="myUserControl" />
```

**And using jQuery you can easily handle a click event on it:**

```
$('#myUserControl').on('click', function(){
    alert('hello from my user control click!');
});
```

Comment: Sorry I want the code to be applied server side just like a button